# window.getSelection() of textarea not working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to get selection text on HTML page.

I use below code, and `window.getSelection()` on textarea seams not work in firefox,
but works fine in Google Chrome.

- I am using firefox 24, and chrome 27.

Here is a sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/AVLCY/

HTML:

```
<div>Text in div</div>
<textarea>Hello textarea</textarea>
<div id='debug'></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('mouseup','body',function(){
   $("#debug").html("You select '" + getSelectionText() + "'");
});

function getSelectionText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        try {
            // return "" in firefox
            return window.getSelection().toString();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Cant get selection text')
        }
    } 
    // For IE
    if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717224/how-to-get-selected-text-in-textarea

Comment: This is due to a [Firefox bug filed in 2001](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686) (yes, 14 years ago).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears `getSelection` does not work on text selected in form fields due to [this Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686).

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10596963/2624466), the workaround is to use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` instead.

Here is a modified example that works correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/AVLCY/1/

Comment: Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: I changed the "textarea" to ":focus", so it works event if there is multiple textarea or input fields : http://jsfiddle.net/AVLCY/653/

Answer (score 1):

It's late 2022 and Firefox still has this weird bug. I went to the original [Bug Report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686) on BugZilla to get more info about this and found a workaround (kindly shared by user **daniel.lee1ibm**):

```js
    //Workaround for Firefox bug 
    const selectedText = document.activeElement.value.substring(
        document.activeElement.selectionStart,
        document.activeElement.selectionEnd
      )
```