# document.getSelection().toString() returns empty string when the text is selected via element.select()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement the following two features:

1. Users can copy the content in a `textarea` by clicking a button.
2. I can know what content users copy (whether users copy with the button, Ctrl-C, or context menu) by listening to the `copy` event.

Here is my code (you can also see it in https://jsfiddle.net/hjtswedm/3/):

```
<html>

<head>
</head>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(window).bind("copy", function (e) {
        alert(document.getSelection().toString());
    });

    var copyText = function () {
        var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
        txt.textContent = $('#data').val();
        txt.style.position = "fixed";
        document.body.appendChild(txt);
        txt.select();
        try {
            return document.execCommand("copy");
        } catch (ex) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            document.body.removeChild(txt);
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <textarea id="data">test copy</textarea>
    <button onclick="copyText()">
    Copy Text
    </button>
</body>

</html>
```

This code works fine with Chrome. However, with Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Edge, when I click the copy button, `document.getSelection().toString()` always returns empty strings. Is this by design, or did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419515/window-getselection-of-textarea-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/wggte9vd/)

Try :

```
 try {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(txt);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    return document.execCommand("copy");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. You fiddle works great for me too, but the code does not work if I save the code to an HTML file and open it in Microsoft Edge (still empty `document.getSelection().toString()`). Could you please help check again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read the following to understand why its only work in chrome and not in firefox. (This is coming from MDN documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection#related_objects)

> It is worth noting that currently getSelection() doesn't work on the
> content of  and  elements in Firefox and Edge
> (Legacy). HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange() or the selectionStart
> and selectionEnd properties could be used to work around this.