# window.getSelection not working in IE and FF with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, summernote

I need to get the highlighted/selected text from Angular Summernote Editor, but I'm getting troubles (I think because of context) with IE (11) and FF (Quantum).

I can get it through `window.getSelection().toString()` at console, but when I use it (or the angular way `$window.getSelection().toString()`) at code, I get nothing in IE and FF.

I've tried with *timeout*, with `document.getSelection()`, with `document.selection` (which throws an exception because *selection* is null or undefined), `activeElement`, `selectionStart`, etc.

I think somewhere in Angular I lost the context of which window am I at, but I don't know why because it works in Chrome.

Also, I've tried with the `editor.createRange` from plugin, but it doesn't gave me the expected result.

Here's my code:

**HTML**:

```
<summernote id="summernote" config="model.comment.summernoteOptions" on-paste="paste(evt)" on-change="change(contents)" ng-model="model.comment.selected.valueTmp"></summernote>
```

**General controller**:

```
$scope.paste = function (evt) {
  $scope.model.comment.normalizeDom(evt);
};
```

**Specific controller**:

```
this.normalizeDom = function (evt) {
  var selected = $window.getSelection().toString();

  console.log(selected);
};
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20419515/863110) question could help you..

Comment: Been there, didn't solve my issue. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sure.. good luck.